# Why do parts of my syntax remain gray in Atom (using One Dark theme)?

Tags: atom-editor

Certain parts of my code are not colored like the tutorial I'm following (my code is top picture, tutorial is bottom picture). If, Else, "Strings", etc..are not colored as they should be. I'm using One Dark theme in Atom. I've tried to change the theme but these portions of my code remain gray. Any ideas why?

[image]

Comment: Which language grammar is in use on these screenshots?

Comment: @idleberg I am using EJS for this section but i've noticed it even when just using HTML.